# Generated class list does not exist {module root}\build\intermediates\data-binding-info\release\_generated.txt

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I am trying to get data binding set up in my Android project, and I am getting an error whenever I try to build. The top of the stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details. Generated class list does not exist C:\git\android-lm\androidCore\build\intermediates\data-binding-info\debug\\_generated .txt
        at android.databinding.tool.util.L.printMessage(L.java:100)
        at android.databinding.tool.util.L.e(L.java:87)
        at android.databinding.tool.util.Preconditions.check(Preconditions.java:25)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBindingBuilder.readGeneratedClasses(DataBindingBuilder.java:130)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBindingBuilder.getJarExcludeList(DataBindingBuilder.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager$16.getExcludeList(LibraryTaskManager.java:550)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.LibraryJarTransform.transform(LibraryJarTransform.java:154)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:151)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:148)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:147)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(A nnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annota tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(Ann otationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
```

Environment:

- Windows 8.1
- Android Studio 1.4.1 (also tried in 1.3)
- Gradle plugin for Android 1.5.0-beta1
- Gradle 2.4
- Build tools 23.0.2
- Target SDK version 23, min version 21 (also tried targeting 22)
- Android Library project depending on a variety of java and other android libraries
- Dagger, dbFlow with apt code generation.

I have removed all code from my project that actually uses types from the data binding libraries - just the act of enabling data binding in my build.gradle causes this error. I have tried clean and rebuild, clearing my `.gradle` folder, clearing all `.\build` folders, restarting android studio but to no avail. The error occurs both from the command line and from within AS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same error. Have you found a solution?

Comment: 握草 ，我也有同样的问题 ，Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have this block:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in a module's `build.gradle` when there are nothing in that module that triggers databinding.